# inserting a dict into sqlite3 column

Tags: python, sqlite, dictionary

i'm trying to store into my db(sqlite3) a dict but it gives me operationalError near dict (i already tried with str(dic) and json.dumps)

```
dict = json.dumps(self.check_list)
conn = sqlite3.connect('----.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(f""""INSERT INTO kit VALUES ('{---}','{----}','{----}','{----}', null,'{dict}', null)""")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

is there a way to store a full dic inside a column?

Comment: It's best to not create SQL on the fly by formatting the string, but use [parameter substitution](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps()` gives you a json string. So just store it like a string. When reading from the db, just convert it back with `json.loads()`.